# Unable to get Networking Working on 16.04 Server

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, dhcp, interface

So a little background.  I'm using a Dell R210 II with Ubuntu Server 16.04.  I was using the server with both on board nics in a LACP lagg and everything was working well.  I recently upgrade most of my lab to 10Gb so I backed up everything and reinstalled ubuntu server onto an SSD but the network has not worked since then with either on the board nics or the 10Gb card.

I have tested the cable and the port on the switch which are working as expected.  I removed the 10Gb card as to eliminate possible issues but still not working and was just trying to get the onboard nics working.

When the interface is set to DHCP, it sends out a request and my router sends an offer but the server doesn't acknowledge or accept the offer. I have no idea what is going on here. I tried to set a static IP address on the interface which does get set correctly but then I'm unable to ping any IP address on the same subnet.  It almost seems like something is blocking data but nothing is coming to mind in either the logs or on the screen.

Below is some info on the system.  Does anyone have any idea on what is going on here or have any ideas on what to try?

*I did set net.ifnames=0 and biosdevnames=0 in my grub file since my 10Gb was being named 'renamed5'.  I experience the same results with or without those commands.

[Photos of Commands and Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIVqi.jpg)

**Update 1:**

- Installed FreeNAS 11 but experienced same issues
- Installed Ubuntu Desktop/Server 16.04.3 but experienced same issues
- Installed Windows 10 and everything worked, so the hardware is still good
- Installed Ubuntu 14.04.5 and it seems to work during the setup but once I logged in, I was able to get a DHCP IP address but then the network is not reachable

**Update 2:**

- Did a restore to one of the original hard drives and it started working but only with the LACP lagg enabled. With DHCP or static on one interface, still doesn't yield any network access.  No idea why it needs to be in the lagg as this will not help me get my 10Gb that I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted my Unifi switches and everything started to work.  I noticed after moving some devices to different ports, they started to exhibit the same behavior.  After restarting everything started to work.